# Problems with remote debugging, /data/local/debugger-socket not on my device

Tags: remote-debugging, firefox-os

I recently flashed Firefox OS 2 on my ZTE Open C, and since then, it is impossible for me to do remote debugging.

I use the following command to forward the required stuff via adb :

`adb forward tcp:$port localfilesystem:/data/local/debugger-socket`

Where $port is usually 6666, but no other port number works.

I checked for `/data/local/debugger-socket` via `ls` in `adb shell`, but the socket isn't listed.

I enabled remote debugging on my phone, so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Does the device even show up in adb? Sounds like you have a borked build.

Comment: Any news? Have you tried to debug with [WebIde](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/WebIDE#Connecting_a_Firefox_OS_device)?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, and sorry about the delay. Actually, my phone repaired itself automagically, and then bricked itself for no reason while I was using a debugging app. We'll never know where that socket went and why it came back...

Comment: Does the device shows up using usb?

Comment: Yup, it showed up using usb. But as I said, the phone is now resting in peace.